# PHP IF statement that looks at MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry, I should have put more information in the question

I am trying to figure out how to create a if statement that looks at a mysql field
for example: if date ("D") = mysqlDateField

I have a small site that users put reminders into a forum to be sent to a specified email address on days they setup.

The days are stored in a mysql database in mon, tue, wed, etc. format.

The users can select multiple days so I have a field for each day (not sure if that is the best way to do it or not)

so I have a sendmail script that runs and sends out the emails with the reminders the users specified.

I want the if statement to check the current day against the day in the database

I am using the date ("D") format currently since it matched what wa stored in the database

After looking around the different forums and w3schools I came up with this below but it is not working, I am new to php and mysql and not exactly sure how to get it working the way I want

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users")or die(mysql_error());
$d = date ("D");

if (mysql_num_rows($result)==$d)
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're new to MySQL and PHP, you should use `PDO`, not `mysql_*` - the other part with your question is: I am new to your style of asking questions and I am not exactly sure what you ask about here.

Comment: your code makes absolutely no sense. `date('D')` gives you a 3 letter version of the current day ('Mon', 'Tue', etc...) and you want to compare that to how many user records you have?

Comment: What is the data type of the column you are trying to compare against? Is it a DATETIME or some string value?

Comment: either pull back the dates that == $d or you will need to loop through $results and query the column in question. A simple google or scan through the php docs would tell you this. Also please dont use mysql function use pdo/mysqli. Look at the php docs and you will find that the function is now depricated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some little note before the code sample:

- creating a date to compare with D is bad, use some more useful
  format like 'Ymd';
- the date you're going to compare must be in the  same format
  (you should not compare a ymd with a ymdhis date) becouse    else they
  will give you inconsistent result. Convert or format the    date
  before using them.
- you are receiving a lot of result via    wildcard query on tables,
  you should avoid when possible a SELECT *

  ```
  foreach($result as $row){    
      if(strtotime($row['field_with_date']) == strtotime($d)){ } }
  ```